# Earth Loop Impedance Meters; Difference between 3 lead (L-N-E) and 2 lead (L-N/E)?

Tags: earth

In our company we use various different brands / models of ELI meters. Some have three leads, live, neutral and earth, and some have only two leads, one live and one neutral/earth combined.

Can anyone tell me the difference between the two types of meter (if any) and how they differ?

Comment: What is an 'ELI meter'?

Comment: GWild guess: ELI=[Earth Loop Impedance](http://www.test-meter.co.uk/17th-edition-test-equipment/loop-testers/)?

Comment: Yep, Earth Loop Impedance meter.

Comment: @JonnyWright I didn't find anything like ELI meter on web. Is it a meter or a testing instrument??

Comment: Test instrument. Here is a 2 lead example: http://www.test-meter.co.uk/products/17th-edition-test-equipment/loop-testers/megger-ltw425-loop-impedance-tester/ Based on the description it seems the two lead variants are used when the neutral may be inaccessible for testing and only an earth is available.